# Send Digital engagement SMS using Messaging template through APEX

Tags: apex, sms, digital-engagement

We have digital engagement license and trying to send SMS through Messaging template .

Throught flow we can able to send to SMS using the Messsaging notification action but I have some requirement to send it as reminder SMS .

So trying to acheive to send SMS through batch Apex but I am not able to find any article in salesforce to send it through APEX.

Can we use APEX to send SMS with messaging template / Messaging notification ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the REST API from your Apex code to send out SMS. Have a look here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_live_message_notification.htm

Or you can upvote this idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmPxUAJ/messaging-send-messages-from-apex-and-flow-not-just-process-builder